# Can you give a simple example of adaptive stepsize scipy.integrate.LSODA function?

Tags: python-3.x, differential-equations, numerical-integration, odeint

I need to understand the mechanism of scipy.integrate.LSODA function.

I have written a test script that integrate a simple function. According to the [LSODA webpage](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.LSODA.html#scipy.integrate.LSODA) inputs of functions can be rhs function, t_min, initial y and t_max. On the other hand, when I run the code, I get nothing. What should I do?

```
import scipy.integrate as integ
import numpy as np

def func(t,y):
    return t

y0=np.array([1])
t_min=1
t_max=10
N_max=100
t_min2=np.linspace(t_min,t_max,N_max)
first_step=0.01

solution=integ.LSODA(func,t_min,y0,t_max)
solution2=integ.odeint(func,y0,t_min2)

print(solution.t,solution.y,solution.nfev,'\n')
print(solution2)
```

Solution give

```
1 [ 1.] 0

[[  1.00000000e+00]
 [  9.48773662e+00]
 [  9.00171421e+01]
 [  8.54058901e+02]
 [  8.10308559e+03]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) You only initiate an instance of the `LSODA` solver class, no computation occurs, just initialization of the arrays with the initial data. To get an `odeint`-like interface, use `solve_ivp` with the option `method='LSODA'`.

2.) Without the option `tfirst=True`, the LSODA solver will solve `y'(t)=t`, while `odeint` will solve `y'(t)=y(t)`

To get comparable results, one should also equalize the tolerances, as the default tolerances can be different. One thus can call the methods like

```
print "LSODA"
solution=integ.solve_ivp(func,[t_min, t_max],y0,method='LSODA', atol=1e-4, rtol=1e-6)
print "odeint"
solution2=integ.odeint(func,y0,t_min2, tfirst=True, atol=1e-4, rtol=1e-6)
```

Even then you get no information on the internal steps of `odeint`, even if the FORTRAN code has an option for that, the python wrapper does not replicate it. You could add a print statement to the ODE function `func` so that you see at what places this function is actually called, this should average to 2 calls with close-by arguments per internal step.

This reports

```
LSODA
1.0 [1.]
1.00995134265 [1.00995134]
1.00995134265 [1.01005037]
1.01990268529 [1.02010074]
1.01990268529 [1.02019977]
10.0 [50.50009903]
10.0 [50.50009903]
odeint
1.0 [1.]
1.00109084546 [1.00109085]
1.00109084546 [1.00109204]
1.00218169092 [1.00218407]
1.00218169092 [1.00218526]
11.9106363102 [71.43162985]
```

where the reported steps in the output of `LSODA` are

```
[ 1.          1.00995134  1.01990269 10.        ] [[ 1.          1.01005037  1.02019977 50.50009903]] 7
```

Of course, a high-order method will integrate the linear polynomial `y'=t` to the quadratic polynomial `y(t)=0.5*(t^2+1)` with essentially no error independent of the step size.